# How to check if a string is matching a sub-string in another string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file contains a lot of C functions' declarations.

For example,

- `void Add (int a, int b);`
- `void AddWithCarry (int a, int b);`

And I am requesting the user to enter the name of the function he wants to delete and then the whole line should be deleted.

I have done the following psuedo code:

1. Check if `line.Contains(string)`
2. If yes, delete the whole line.
3. If not, check the other line.

It worked fine if the user requests to delete `AddWithCarry` function, but if the user requests to delete the `Add` function, both lines will be deleted as both of them contains the `Add` string.

How could I overcome this problem ?

Comment: how about `line.Contains(string + " (")` ?

Comment: Look at your 2 samples. The presence of `"Add"` isn't enough to make the distinction. So you need extra checks. The only 100% reliable way would require a full C parser and preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your if with:
if(line.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Contains(string + "("))

Not the prettiest way, but should work, as long as function calls are in format of : funcName();